# Choose strata size so that dispersion of an estimator is the least

Tags: variance, estimation, sampling

The reseacher has 20000 dollars in their disposition to run a survey. It's known that from all households, 90% have stationary phones. Interview by phone costs 10 dollars per household. Each personified survey costs 30 dollars and if the respondents are to be surveyed in person the survey costs are 40 dollars ( additional transportation costs). Supposing that variance within strata with or without phones are similar and fixed costs $c_0 = 5000$ dollars, find how many households should be surveyed in each strata to get minimal variance for the estimator in case of  1) each household is surveyed by personal interviews 2) households without phones are surveyed in person and households that have phone are surveyed by phone.

Formula for variance:
$$D_{min} = \frac{(\sum^H_{h=1} W_h S_h)^2}{n} - \frac{\sum_{h=1}^H W_hS_h^2}{N}$$.

I need to find amount of surveyers in each strata:

$$n_h = \frac{(C-c_0)N_hS_h / \sqrt{c_h}}{\sum^H_{h=1} N_iS_i / \sqrt{c_i}}$$

But I don't neither $N, S_h$ or $N_h$ so how can I solve this?
The way I tried to do it, was:
as $S_1 \approx S_2:$
$$n_1 = \frac{15 000 \cdot N_1 S / \sqrt{40}}{S(N_1 / \sqrt{40} + N_2 / \sqrt{50})} \Rightarrow n_1 = \frac{15000 \cdot N_1 / \sqrt{40}}{N_1 / \sqrt{40} + N_2 / \sqrt{50}}$$
and $$n_2 = \frac{15000 \cdot N_2 / \sqrt{50}}{N_1 / \sqrt{40} + N_2 / \sqrt{50}}$$
We could rewrite the formula form $D_{min}$ as: $$D_{min} = \frac{N( \sum^H_{h=1}W_hS_h)^2 - n\sum^H_{h=1} W_hS_h^2}{nN}$$
Then to minimise the variance, we should minimise $N( \sum^H_{h=1}W_hS_h)^2 - n\sum^H_{h=1} W_hS_h^2 \rightarrow min$
Rewriting the expression considering that the variances for both strata (with and without telephones) are equal, we get:
$$N\cdot S^2(W_1+W_2)^2-nS^2(W_1+W_2) = = S^2(N-n)$$
But that doesn't give any result as to how to choose the strata size. $n = n_1+n_2 $ should be maximised. But $n_1$ and $n_2$ are expressed through $N_1$ and $N_2$ which cannot be chosen. Please help to solve this.